# Matrix Multiplication mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm working on the matrix multiplication using mapreduce. I built a jar file using the code below. the code works perfectly fine with smaller matrices but when the files becomes large the mapping phase will stop at 67% then it will give me this errors below:

```
Java.Lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at MatrixMult$mapper.map(MatrixMult.java:44)
    at Matrix$mapper.map(MatrixMult.java:1)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Maptask.runNewMapper(mapTask.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.maptask.run(maptask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.yarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.accesscontroller.dopriviledged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.subject.doAs(Subject.Java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

mapreduce worked when I used a smaller matrix. I will post the code for mapper and reducer below:

```
public class Map
  extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
                int m = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("m"));
                int p = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("p"));
                String line = value.toString();
                // (M, i, j, Mij);
                String[] indicesAndValue = line.split(",");
                Text outputKey = new Text();
                Text outputValue = new Text();
                if (indicesAndValue[0].equals("M")) {
                        for (int k = 0; k < p; k++) {
                                outputKey.set(indicesAndValue[1] + "," + k);
                                // outputKey.set(i,k);
                                outputValue.set(indicesAndValue[0] + "," + indicesAndValue[2]
                                                + "," + indicesAndValue[3]);
                                // outputValue.set(M,j,Mij);
                                context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
                        }
                } else {
                        // (N, j, k, Njk);
                        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                                outputKey.set(i + "," + indicesAndValue[2]);
                                outputValue.set("N," + indicesAndValue[1] + ","
                                                + indicesAndValue[3]);
                                context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
                        }
                }
        }
}




public class Reduce
  extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                String[] value;
                //key=(i,k),
                //Values = [(M/N,j,V/W),..]
                HashMap<Integer, Float> hashA = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
                HashMap<Integer, Float> hashB = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
                for (Text val : values) {
                        value = val.toString().split(",");
                        if (value[0].equals("M")) {
                                hashA.put(Integer.parseInt(value[1]), Float.parseFloat(value[2]));
                        } else {
                                hashB.put(Integer.parseInt(value[1]), Float.parseFloat(value[2]));
                        }
                }
                int n = Integer.parseInt(context.getConfiguration().get("n"));
                float result = 0.0f;
                float m_ij;
                float n_jk;
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                        m_ij = hashA.containsKey(j) ? hashA.get(j) : 0.0f;
                        n_jk = hashB.containsKey(j) ? hashB.get(j) : 0.0f;
                        result += m_ij * n_jk;
                }
                if (result != 0.0f) {
                        context.write(null,
                                        new Text(key.toString() + "," + Float.toString(result)));
                }
        }
}



public class MatrixMultiply {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: MatrixMultiply <in_dir> <out_dir>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        // M is an m-by-n matrix; N is an n-by-p matrix.
        conf.set("m", "1000");
        conf.set("n", "100");
        conf.set("p", "1000");
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                Job job = new Job(conf, "MatrixMultiply");
        job.setJarByClass(MatrixMultiply.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure where the error is coming from but I know whenever I use a large file I run into this issue

Comment: Instead of sharing your codes via an external link, you need to post relevant pieces of your code here. You should also explain what the error you received was. As it stands, your problem is very uncertain. Try to make it more understandable.

Comment: the question fixed would you try answering the question please?

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it